# DirectShow Filter Graph Editor doesn't show remote graphs

Tags: directshow, graphedit

I have a problem with connecting to remote graph from DirectShow Filter Graph Editor. When I run application that creates a direct show graph, on my Windows XP machine graph is shown in the list of remote graphs, but on the Windows 7 (x64) machine list of remote graphs is empty.  I have registered proppage.dll and also registered directshowspy.dll ... but still no results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a `proppage.dll` and an `x64/proppage.dll` and you'll need to register both to ensure that both x64 and x86 apps work.

The DLL files should be available with the Windows SDK. In case of the Windows 10 SDK, for example, the files will typically reside in the `x64` and `x86` folders in the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\bin\%version%` folder, with `%version%` being the installed version of the SDK (e.g. `10.0.18362.0`).

Comment: both are already registered...tried several times to unregister/register...nothing...

Comment: are you running with admin privileges? If you're running one app under the debugger with elevated permissions it might not be able to view the other.

Comment: UAC is turned off, and registrations were performed as admin, while I'm trying to connect to graph as not admin

Comment: For me - I had to register proppage.dll from the Windows SDK and then run graphedt as my normal user ID. The application runs with my user id and so graphedt has to use the same user id. Running graphedt as admin did not show the remote graph. I registered both the x64 and x86 versions of proppage.dll and my application is x86 and is now being shown in graphedt ok.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I first moved to Windows 7.  A DirectShow is composed of filters that are either built for x86 or x64 architecture.

If you're registering the x64 version of DirectShowSpy.dll, don't expect to be able to spy on a graph that uses x86 filters.

Get the x86 version of DirectShowSpy.dll, unregister your installed version and then install the x86 version.

I keep both versions of DirectShowSpy.dll on my machine and register the appropriate one for working on specific graphs.

I also recommend [RadScorpion's GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/) ;)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same application that works in XP but not in Windows 7?  The app needs to manually expose its graph to the Running Object Table so that GraphEdit will see it.

Example here: http://forum.inmatrix.com/index.php?showtopic=4439&view=findpost&p=19994

Comment: It exposes graph to the ROT, everything works well on Windows XP machine, even on some other Windows 7 machines. It looks like that there is something wrong on my machine, but can no figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got same problem and figure out that `GraphEdit` must be run at the Admin level.
Otherwise, I can not see any remote graph.

Comment: As mentioned at [1] and below - you have to register proppage.dll on Vista and Windows7. You do not need to run as admin. ( [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390650(v=vs.85).aspx)